# News Ticker For multiple RSS Feeds

Tags: newsfeed

We are looking at putting a news ticker onto the front page of our site, we would like it to be a feed from various rss feeds on the site, so people can see what is happening on the site. I have found a couple of possibilities that will take a single rss feed, but none that will take multiple ones.

Any body any suggestions/alternative ways of doing it?

Cheers
Luke

Comment: Is this custom coded?

Comment: not sure what you mean, we have a custom master page so putting some code in is not an issue

Comment: I mean, I wrote a custom news ticker in Silverlight, but you could just as easily write one as a web part. I could write you up the whole logic to do it, but this isn't as easy as pointing to a couple links and having it work. I don't know of any third party tools that would do this, but I'm sure there's something out there if you want to go that route.

Comment: i couldn't really find anything third party that was free, i did consider altering jQuery-News-Ticker to try and make that accept more than one feed, that seemed like the easiest and most open option

Answer (score 1):

We decided to use the out the box RSS feed reader. As it only takes one RSS feed we used [Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/) to combine several RSS feeds into one. The nice thing about pipes as well is that we could change the amount of articles to include from each feed. Some sites like BBC can have lots of items so will swamp the RSS feed reader so that all people will see. Also with pipes I hacked around with what is returned to remove images to keep a coherent look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a content query web part to roll up content from within your site.  You could also try using a product like the Lightning Conductor web part from Lightning Tools or the similar offering from Bamboo Solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One other option (out-of-the-box) is to rely on SharePoint Enterprise Search Federation to retrieve RSS Feeds (available on your SharePoint Sites or external) which also allow for authenticated sites.

Couple of videos here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff960988#lesson5 to give you an idea.

Comment: we've not got enterprise version, so i dont think we can use this

Comment: a little clarification: Enterprise Search (and federated search) comes already with Standard license (is just the name that would generate confusion).